# Random ERROLEVEL 2 on CHKDSK run

Tags: chkdsk, error-logging

On an always-on Windows Server 2008 R2, hard disks are verified weekly with Chkdsk /F command.

Randomly, apparently without a real reason, every 2/3 weeks, chkdsk will return errorlevel 2.

I wonder if there's a way to identify the offending program / service.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to my Yahoo, code 2 means
**"Disk cleanup, such as garbage collection, was performed, or cleanup was not performed because /f was not specified"**.

So that could be a routine situation without any offending programs.